In a Jenkins pipeline, is there a way to disable displaying a certain job run?
I have multi-branch pipeline job with a Jenkinsfile that has the following code. It works the way I want, per the comments.
node("linux-node") {
  // Check if this build is triggered upstream or manually.
  final boolean triggeredUpstreamOrManually = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(Cause.UpstreamCause) != null ||
                                              currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(Cause.UserIdCause) != null
  if (triggeredUpstreamOrManually) {
    // If so, we proceed as normal and call the script that does the build.
    def obj = new MyBuilder(this, env.CONFIRM.toBoolean(), env.DEBUG_LEVEL.toInteger())
    obj.buildBranch(env.BRANCH_NAME.trim())
  }
  else {
    // Else, the build is triggered via indexing. For this, we trigger the top level build job,
    // which will eventually call this build and execute the code in the if(true) clause. 
    build job: "SomeOtherBuildJob",
          parameters: [
             // some parameters
          ],
          wait: false
  }
}

However, on the job's page I see this, where build #2243 is the result of the code in the else{} clause above. Is there a way to suppress or hide this build run on the UI?

